# Ajax POST request becomes a GET request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying out Redis and wanted to build a simple front end / back end setup to test it and to practice. The front end is HTML / Javascript / JQuery and the back end is PHP / Apache / Redis. Basically, I wanted to send a post request to the back end and receive a response, that I would then display on the web console. To send the request, I used JQuery:

```
var data = $("#login_form :input").serializeArray();

var username = data[0]['value'];
var password = data[1]['value'];

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/Convo/user.php?jsoncallback=%3F",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: { username: username, password: password, method: "create" },
        success: function(text){console.log("awesome");}
        });
```

I am using Firebug on Firefox to see what is really going on. In Firebug, I see a GET request being fired instead of a POST. The jsoncallback string attached to the url might be the cause, but without it, I don't get a response at all. As a side note, I am expecting json back in response. Here is my PHP code:

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require 'Predis/Autoloader.php';
Predis\Autoloader::register();

$body = array();
$head = array();

$redis = new Predis\Client(array(
        'scheme' => 'tcp',
        'host'   => '127.0.1.1',
        'port'   => 6379,
));

if(!$redis)
{
    $body['status'] = "fail";
    $body['message'] = "unable to connect to database";
    $head['body'] = $body;

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($head);
    exit;
}
else
{
    $body['status'] = "success";
    $body['message'] = "connected to database!";
    $head['body'] = $body;
    $jsoncallback = $_POST['jsoncallback'];

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $jsoncallback . '(' . json_encode($head) . ')';
    exit;
}
```

The jsoncallback stuff was the only way to get a response, but how do I successfully launch a true POST request without it?

Comment: Why did you set that get parameter at all? It doesn't seem needed in your script

Comment: it isn't possible to POST with the jsonp datatype.

Comment: According to an answer I found on another question, the data returned from PHP has to be "wrapped" by the jsoncallback that is sent via get. Without all the jsoncallback stuff, the request is fired but nothing is returned

Comment: I use "text" as datatype for my posts, but you might want json, instead of jsonp

Comment: I changed it to json, but it still changed into a GET request.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably because you are using jsonp as dataType, jsonp doesn't support POST requests.

Edit: Try sending your jsoncallback parameter, with the other parameters:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/Convo/user.php",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: { username: username, password: password, method: "create", jsoncallback: "%3F" },
        success: function(text){console.log("awesome");}
        });
```

Comment: I changed the dataType to "json" and I removed the jsoncallback stuff. The post gets fired but nothing is returned. I even wrote to a file in the php script to make sure it was executed and it was.

Comment: You are sending a "?" as the parameter jsoncallback? If so, try %3F instead of "?"

Comment: As in jsoncallback=%3F because I just tried it and still no response

Comment: try change $jsoncallback = $_GET['jsoncallback']; to $jsoncallback = $_POST['jsoncallback']; or change the ajax type to "GET"

Comment: Changing the php file gets me an error that says jsoncallback is undefined. Changing the ajax type changes it to a GET request, which is the opposite of what I need.

Comment: Are you still sending jsoncallback as a parameter?, did you changed your dataType in ajax to json? please, update the first post if possible.

Comment: Yes, I am still sending jsoncallback as a parameter and it is set to %3F. The dataType is json.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that adding this line to my php file fixed the issue:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

I understand that this is not best practice but I was at the end of my rope. It was a cross site prohibition that prevented a response from returning to my front end. I am also aware that there is a way to filter this so that only certain sites can make requests.